# Why am I no longer able to deploy functions (Error 503)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

No longer able to deploy cloud function via "firebase deploy" command - receiving error: "**HTTP Error: 503, The service is currently unavailable**"

I previously had a single function deployed and working until a slight modification was causing an authentication error, so I temporarily deleted it until I had time to fix the error.

So a couple days pass, I modify the original code (just added a bit of code relating to service account credentials, didn't even modify the actual function) and tried to re-deploy it (using 'firebase deploy') however it's throwing the following error: "HTTP Error: 503, The service is currently unavailable".

I thought maybe the service is currently down, but Firebase Status Dashboard shows all services are green and noone else seems to be complaining about this error at the moment. I've tried reinstalling/updating firebase-tools and even reverting the functions index.js code back to what it had been when I last successfully deployed, but same error every time. I don't think it has anything to do with the code on my end, but perhaps some weird bug relating to my account/api/authentication.

I've submitted a tech support question on firebase and am awaiting response, but thought I'd try my luck here as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Maybe I put this in the wrong section then, but as I mentioned in the OP, I'm almost certain the problem I'm having isn't in my code (as the error also indicates), so unless someone gives me a reason to think otherwise I thought it pointless including any. As for the desired behavior, it kind of goes without saying... the function get's deployed without the aforementioned error?

Comment: I think this is more of a server-side issue relating to my account/api. I'd hoped someone may have experience with it and could offer some suggestions as it's probably not something easily reproducible. For the record, I have tried disabling and re-enabling my cloud functions API.

Answer (score 2):

After some back and forth with firebase technical support, turns out it is some strange bug on their server end (in relation to this particular project) as I'm able to deploy the same functions no problem to other projects. It may have been "triggered" initially by hitting a function invocation quota when I was having issues with one of the functions in the past (an issue which somehow caused the function to be repeatedly called until I realized and deleted it 2 days after). However the project should no longer be limited and I still am unable to deploy any functions on that particular project.

The issue has been handed onto their engineers and hopefully will have it resolved on their end soon.